# Parsing Sprites from Spritesheet

Tags: c++, sprites, spritesheet, texture-atlas, asset-workflow

How can I parse a spritesheet consisting of scattered sprites with different sizes, [like this example](https://www.spriters-resource.com/mobile/angrybirds/sheet/66439/) and return the `(x, y)` and `(width, height)` values of each sprite?

It is trivial when the spritesheet is split on equal widths and heights, which for this thing I envy Unity for.

After spending some time researching, the best I could find is http://www.spritecow.com/, which is Javascript based and you have to manually click on your sprites to parse a single sprite, moreover it is really slow.

Comment: The spritecow site includes a [link to their github](https://github.com/jakearchibald/sprite-cow) - did you look at how they implemented their solution?